# Expansion of tilde in zsh

Tags: zsh, tilde

I stumbled upon this behavior of zsh when using FreeBSD:

```
% dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1 of=~/test2
dd: failed to open '~/test2': No such file or directory
```

This really confused me because the same thing works just fine in bash.

I can `touch` files using tilde in zsh, and then `ls` them:

```
% touch ~/test2
% ls ~/test2
/home/christoph/test2
```

At first, I assumed that zsh doesn't realize that there comes a path after `of=` so it didn't expand `~`. But autocompleting file names works just fine. In fact, if use an existing file name, begin its path with `~`, and then hit Tab at some point, the path gets expanded in the command I'm typing in.

Why does zsh pass `~/test2` to `dd`, not `/home/christoph/test2`?

zsh behaves the same on Linux. In fact, I executed these commands above and copied their outputs on a Linux machine.

Comment: You can use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`~` is expanded only in a few contexts](/a/146697). POSIX, for the standard `sh` mandates `echo a=~` to output `a=~` (while it mandates `~` to be expanded in `a=~` alone).

`zsh` however has a `magicequalsubst` option which you can use for `~` to be expanded after `=` even if it's not in assigments or arguments to the `export`/`typeset`... pseudo-keywords.

So:

```
$ echo a=~
a=~
$ set -o magicequalsubst
$ echo a=~
a=/home/chazelas
```

Note that `bash`, when not in POSIX/`sh` mode, expands `~` in `word=~` but only when what's on the left of `=` looks like a literal unquoted `bash` variable name (regardless of whether it's in arguments to `typeset`/`declare`/`export` or any other command):

```
$ bash -c 'echo a=~'
a=/home/chazelas
$ bash -c 'echo "a"=~'
a=~
$ bash -c 'var=a; echo $var=~'
a=~
$ bash -c 'echo a.b=~'
a.b=~
$ (exec -a sh bash -c 'echo a=~')
a=~
```