# WGET gives "No such file or directory" error when -O option is a variable

Tags: zsh, wget, macos

When I do this, it works perfectly and downloads the file at the required path.

```
wget -O ~/Temp/my.file "https://github.com/sometool/releases/latest/download/the.file"
```

But when I do this:

```
PATH="~/Temp/my.file"
wget -O $PATH "https://github.com/sometool/releases/latest/download/the.file"
```

It says:

`~/Temp/my.file: No such file or directory`

I've tried with or without quotes, wrapped in $(echo $PATH), always the same error.

I am using MacOS Terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expansion of tilde in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373519/expansion-of-tilde-in-zsh) (assuming it's a ZSH script).

Comment: @Kulfy The answer there states, correctly, that the code posted in the question should work as intended.

Comment: The code you posted here would not have the effect you describe. Not only because `~` _is_ expanded there, so you would see the path to your home directory there, but because `PATH` is a system variable that indicates where to find commands, so the actual effect of the code you posted would be `zsh: command not found: wget`. Please copy-paste what you actually typed. Preferably in a new terminal tab, since you might have done some weird reconfiguration in that shell before the part you posted.

Comment: @Gilles Did you mean `set -o magicequalsubst` won't make any difference?

Comment: Indeed @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'. I edited my question. I had double quotes around the path in the variable assignment. Removing these did fix the problem.

Comment: Remove the double quotes around the tilde. Your revised question is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/does-always-equal-home/146697#146697 . See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes

Comment: @Kulfy `magicequalsubst` only affects equal signs that are not variable assignments. `PATH=…` is a variable assignment, so an unquoted tilde at the beginning is always expanded.

Comment: This could also happen if the folder does not exist (i.e. if there's a typo in the folder name)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, removing quotes in the variable declaration fixed it:

```
PATH=~/Temp/my.file
```

More details provided at:

[Does ~ always equal $HOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/does-always-equal-home/146697#146697)

[Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)